RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1391:15)
``RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1391:15)
    at sync (C:\hotel-management-system\backend\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:74:13)
    at sync (C:\hotel-management-system\backend\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:80:24)
    at sync (C:\hotel-management-system\backend\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:80:24)
    at sync (C:\hotel-management-system\backend\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:80:24)
    at sync (C:\hotel-management-system\backend\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:80:24)
    at sync (C:\hotel-management-system\backend\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:80:24)
    at sync (C:\hotel-management-system\backend\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:80:24)
    at sync (C:\hotel-management-system\backend\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:80:24)
    at sync (C:\hotel-management-system\backend\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:80:24)`

Please help me!
I could not run my NestJS backend with PostgreSQL and PGadmin due to this error while I'm trying to run the project:
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1391:15)`
